# Extract values from text and convert to JSON using python

Tags: python, text

I have a text in a file as shown below. I need to extract values from text as json format.

**Input.txt**

```
   - - - - - —---
   Name: Game
   Students: 10
   Sql : case @
         when students.db end
   LIST: write

   Total:Game1
   - - - - - —---
   Name: Game1
   Students: 10
   Sql : case @
         when students1.db end
   LIST: write
   Attribute: PL Game1
   - - - - - - - - - - - 
   Name: Game11
   Students: 10
   Sql : case @
         when students11.db end
   LIST: write
 - - - - - - - - -
```

Using python i need to get output as 
**Output**

```
{"NAME" :"Game" } 
{"SQL" :"case @ when students1.db end" }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any part in particular you are struggling with?

Comment: I used split and replace method. But i am not getting proper format

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you provided in your question, on way to do it is this:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as inFile:
    finalOutput = []
    content = inFile.read().replace('-','').replace('—','').replace('@\n', '@').strip().split('\n\n')
    content = [" ".join(item.split()) for elem in content for item in elem.split('\n')]
    content = [elem for elem in content if elem != '']
    finalOutput = [{elem.split(":")[0].strip() : elem.split(":")[1].strip()} for elem in content]
    for elem in finalOutput:
        print(elem)
```

This will yield the following result:

```
{'Name': 'Game'}
{'Students': '10'}
{'Sql': 'case @ when students.db end'}
{'LIST': 'write'}
{'Total': 'Game1'}
{'Name': 'Game1'}
{'Students': '10'}
{'Sql': 'case @ when students1.db end'}
{'LIST': 'write'}
{'Attribute': 'PL Game1'}
{'Name': 'Game11'}
{'Students': '10'}
{'Sql': 'case @ when students11.db end'}
{'LIST': 'write'}
```